# Site guest user cannot create ContentDocumentLink - insufficient access rights on cross-reference id

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com, contentdocument

**[SOLVED by removing trigger on ContentDocumentLink]**

I am implementing uploading files as ContentDocument. For System Administrator all works good, but for non-registered site user it does not work. 
Creation of `ContentVersion` is good, but it fails at creation of `ContentDocumentLink` with exception `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY`.
Btw site user can successfully create all other objects (Opportunity, Account etc..)

I removed all dml except this one. I hardcoded Ids of existing `ContentDocument` and existing `Opportunity`. Owner of ContentDocument and Opportunity records is Site Guest User. And it fails only at creating `ContentDocumentLink`
And Query for both Opportunity and ContentDocuments returns existing data. So User has access to both objects.

```
// ...       
       ContentDocumentLink link = new ContentDocumentLink(
           ContentDocumentId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
           ShareType = 'I',
           LinkedEntityId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
       );
       insert link;
// ...
```

Comment: This may be a access permission issue. CRM Content Access is not available for Guest Users. Check this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cH2vAAE) link.

Comment: @SarojBera System administrator also has 'Salesforce CRM Content User' disabled, but all works

Comment: Hi @VladyslavKushney, it would help to see your sample code that reproduces the problem. The cross reference error usually means the running user either (A) doesn't have sharing access to the record or (B) the record being shared to doesn't exist. Double check the values for your lookup fields.

Comment: @DougAyers Please see edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I remove `trigger CDL on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {...}`

Comment: Hi, having same issue when i am going to create ContentDocumentLink with Guest User From portal it is not creating. Can you please give the solution what you have applied.

Comment: That's not very helpful if other code needs to have a ContentDocumentLink trigger. Do you mean you deleted the trigger or just disabled it? I hate when salesforce tries to make things better, but actually makes things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ShareType = 'V'` instead of 'I'. The problem may be that Guest Users can only grant view access and not other share types. I've run into similar quirks myself with ShareType when [developing Attachment to Files conversion code](https://github.com/DouglasCAyers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/blob/master/src/classes/ConvertAttachmentsToFilesService.cls#L180).

> 'V': Viewer premission. The user can explicitly view but not edit the shared file.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help

Comment: Hey, try to add a trigger like my and see if it works for you.